# How to start the PyQt5 designer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

I am unable to find the Qt5 designer.exe. I have looked into a folder such as

```
C:\Users\ranar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5
```

There is a file in this folder with the name QtDesigner. But it is not executable, it is a python file.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt5 designer.exe is available in the

```
C:\Users\ranar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PySide6
```

folder.In this folder click on the designer.exe file and the designer will open.
In case you don't have pyside6, then use the following

```
pip install PySide6
```

Then you are good to go.

Comment: The OP is asking about PyQt5, not PySide6.

Comment: @musicamante It's a self-answer.

Comment: @eyllanesc Right, I didn't notice it. Still, it seems off: the versions and libraries don't match.